# Problem while trying to convert C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++

I've been trying to convert a part of C# to C++ but I can't find out why it's not working.

The C# code:

```
FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
fileStream.Seek(4L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, 8);
fileStream.Seek(4L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
fileStream.Write(buffer, 4, 4);
fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, 4);
fileStream.Flush();
fileStream.Close();
```

My C++ convertion:

```
std::fstream fileStream("file.dtx");

if (fileStream.is_open()) {
    fileStream.seekg(0, fileStream.end);
    int length = fileStream.tellg();
    fileStream.seekg(0, fileStream.beg);

    char* buffer = new char[8];

    fileStream.seekg(4, fileStream.beg);
    fileStream.read(buffer, 8);
    fileStream.seekg(4, fileStream.beg);
    fileStream.write(buffer, 4);
    fileStream.write(buffer, 0);
    fileStream.flush();
    fileStream.close();

    delete[] buffer;
    printf("Done!");
}
```

Comment: Care to be a wee bit more specific than "it's not working" ? That's only slightly less nebulous that "something's wrong". Details. What *is* it doing? What is it *supposed* to be doing? What seems to be different? And what did you discover thus far while *debugging* it ?

Comment: while trying to read I'm not getting any output, I don't really see why honestly, that's why I wanted to ask on stackoverflow :s.

Comment: Also, C++ is not C#. Get rid of `new`/ and `delete`, and simply declare `char buffer[8]`. Now, carefully review the technical specifications for C#'s `Write`() calls, and C++'s `write()` call. Wrap your brain around the fact that one has three parameters, the other has two. Function parameters, in both cases, exist for a reason. If you study what each parameter is used for, in C#, which is the corresponding remaining parameter in the C++ version, and then think about what needs to be done to implement the equivalent functionality ***of the missing parameter***, the answer should be obvious.

Comment: Looks like you are using `seekg` when you ought to be using `seekp`.  May be a non-issue on your platform depending on their implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your C#

```
fileStream.Write(buffer, 4, 4); // Write bytes 4-7 from buffer
fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, 4); // Write bytes 0-3 from buffer
```

Your C++

```
fileStream.write(buffer, 4); // Write bytes 0-3 from buffer
fileStream.write(buffer, 0); // Write nothing
```

What you want

```
fileStream.write(buffer + 4, 4); // Write bytes 4-7 from buffer
fileStream.write(buffer, 4);     // Write bytes 0-3 from buffer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it's working fine. I don't know why I was looking at other things.. :x